# What is the second parameter in savedInstanceState.getInt?

Tags: android, bundle, android-savedstate

I'd like to understand something from the following Android fragment docs:
[Android fragment docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

In the example at the end of the page, the mCurCheckPosition int is saved in a bundle as "curChoice":

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    }
```

However, at the start of the example, when checking for and possibly retrieving "curChoice", there is a second parameter '0' that is provided:

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }
```

What is this zero doing there? Surely the point of referencing "curChoice" is to retrieve the value that was saved under it in the first place?

Comment: When the value did not exist ,it will not return null .And it will return the second parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is this zero doing there?

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#getInt(java.lang.String,%20int)), it is the "value to return if [the] key does not exist".

> Surely the point of referencing "curChoice" is to retrieve the value that was saved under it in the first place?

Yes, and in this case, the default value would seem to be superfluous. In general, the default value is for cases where the key is conditionally added to the `Bundle`, so the consumer of the `Bundle` can cleanly handle the case where the key was not added.

Answer (score 2):

> **Surely the point of referencing "curChoice" is to retrieve the value that was saved under it in the first place?**

I replied to it: 
Yeah, developer intention is clear to get the value saved in savedInstance , but
There may be situation :

> key ,given to retrieve the value !=  Key, to insert the data in
>   savedInstance

So developer also provide a default value (O in your case) **that is used to prevent from null pointer exception**

Answer (score 0):

It's the default value to assign to "mCurCheckPosition" in case there is no "curChoice" key in the savedInstanceState. Think of it as a case where the fragment is getting restored(so savedInstanceState won't be null) but there is no "curChoice".